# Remotely shutdown ESX from Windows

Tags: windows, vmware-esx

Is there a way to (initiate) shutdown an ESX server remotely from Windows, similarly to the 
`shutdown -m \\server ...` 
command?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A better option is that you can install the [PowerCLI tools](http://communities.vmware.com/community/vmtn/vsphere/automationtools/powercli) and then use [a script](http://spininfo.homelinux.com/news/vSphere_PowerCLI/2010/06/18/Shutdown_infrastructure_on_power_outage) to shut it down.  This method works without having to enable anything on the server (I'm not sure about ESX but SSH is unsupported in ESXi).

Comment: This is the "better" option from a long-term perspective. ESX won't be around forever.

Comment: Okay, I think I like this option the best.  Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

SSH to the ESX server and shut it down?

Comment: Ok, but can that be automated?

Comment: Setup ssh key-based-authentication.  Use `plink` with the keys to authenticate and shutdown?

Comment: I'll give that a shot